# Как вернуть несколько значений из функции в C#

Tags: c#, c#-faq

Как вернуть несколько значений из функции в C#

Answer (score 18, accepted):

В версиях C# c 4 по 6 включительно, лучшими вариантами вернуть из функции(метода вернее), являлись возвращение кортежа Tuple<> или создание класса\структуры с нужными свойствами. Вариант с out-параметрами, хуже, т.к. немного выбивается из основных парадигм применяемых при разработке на C#, и был встроен скорее для поддержки импорта нативных функций.

На сегодняшний день (C#7) удобной и достаточно качественной альтернативой является использование кортежей поддерживаемых на уровне синтаксиса языка при помощи значимого типа ValueTuple (Правда требуется добавлять библиотеку System.ValueTuple, например через NuGet).

---

#### возвращение кортежа Tuple<>

```
public Tuple<string, int> GetVasya()
{
     return Tuple.Create("Вася", 16);
}
```

#### создание класса

```
class Person
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Age {get;set;}
}

...

public Person GetVasya()
{
     return new Person { Name = "Вася", Age = 16 };
}
```

#### использование ValueTuple

```
public (string Name, int Age) GetVasya()
{
     return ("Вася", 16);
}
```

Comment: Тем не менее, как раз в C# 7 out-параметры получили второе рождение благодаря конструкции out var.

Comment: @PavelMayorov + деконструкторы

Answer (score 20):

Для того чтобы вернуть несколько значений из функции, нужно объявить необходимые параметры с модификаторами out. Например.

```
 class SomeClass
 {
    public int getManyData(out object outData1, out object outData2) {
        // Код функции
        outData1 = someValue1; // Необходимо инициализировать выходной параметр
        outData2 = someValue2; // Необходимо инициализировать выходной параметр
        return result;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 19):

Вернуть [Tuple<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx)